# Webpack & Css-loader. How to create dynamic className for React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

The project has the following reference, which returns a string:

```
const left = slide.imageLeft; // introLeft
```

And further renders it inside React Component. But it returns as a string `styles.imageLeft` and since webpack doest convert it into corresponding bundled class like `914u923asdsajdlj1l23` the styles are not applied.

```
<div className={`styles.${left}`}>&nbsp;</div>
```

**P.S** I did try to eval, but it drops 2 errors.

```
There is an internal error in the React performance measurement code. Did not expect componentDidMount timer to start while render timer is still in progress for another instance.
```

**And**

```
ReferenceError: styles is not defined
```

Can you please suggest the possible ways to achieve dynamic class generation for css-loader.

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you wish to achieve and what the current problem is? Are you using the CSS modules option provided by css-loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the style within the `render()`, or within the component definition, like this

```
render: function(){
  var myStyle = {
    // your style rules go here
  };
  return(
    <div style={myStyle}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

in a way, this is already dynamic, because all you have to do is to change to style and it'll make sure that the component will re-render on update